# How to keep track of color of items in a gridview in an activity

Tags: android, gridview

My Custom adapter class -

```
public class CAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] values;
public int[] clicked;
public int[] allVisited;...
```

if clicked is one - the item is yellow - indicating this item in gridview has been clicked at least once
if allVisited is one - the item is red - indicating a condition linked to this item in the subactivity which is triggered on item click.

the item is an imageview + textview whose background color is being set in onitemclick in gridview activity oncreate or getview in custom adapter class.

How to keep track of these values between the activation and deactivation of the activity.
Do we need to do this thru passing values between activities in databundles and even then it is not obvious.

Also is it better to use the back button of the device here or a button click from the activity to go back to another activity.

Apart from this - is it possible to stop running an app completely when a custom button presented for this (like Exit) is clicked in the main activity, and how?

Please help. I am new in Android. Thanks, Sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

First off to exit the Main activity just call the  [*finish method*.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)
This method closes the activity it is called on, so you can also use it for closing secondary activities. It basically simulates the back key.

To keep the background colors just open the activities from the main activity and close them with the finish method when you're done with them. It should restore the last layout on returning to the main activity.

---

Start your activity like this:

```
startActivityForResult(activity, REQUESTED_RETURN_RESULT);
```

In your main activity you override the OnActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case REQUESTED_RETURN_RESULT:
            handleStuff(data);
        break;
        case SOME_OTHER_REQUEST:
            handleSomethingElse(data);
        break;
     }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In your secondary activity change the finish() method to include:

```
Intent _result = new Intent();              
_result.setData(DATA_TO_RETURN_TO_THE_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, _result);
finish();
```

*you could also check if it is the correct data by returning and checking the resultCode*

Comment: Ok Gr8. I tried it and thats how it works - thanks - only there is a system message - unfortunately the app has stopped when i close the main activity - is it possible to change this message to good bye for example...

Comment: Also in my gridview activity i am coloring some items depending on some conditions in a subactivity - so when that activity finishes i need to know the state of a flag for each item. How can i do this - either i have to pass a bundle but for that i will have to activate the gridview activity - or can i control the colors in the parent activity from the code in the subactivity. Please write soon kindly. Thanks so much..., Sanjay.

Comment: If it is saying "unfortunately the app has stopped" it means it has crashed. In order to solve this I will need to see the stack trace.

Comment: As for your second comment you should use startActivityForResult. I've updated the main post with example code.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will soon try this. The app was crashing actually because the click handler had the parameter View missing. So it seems even in the main activity just finish() works as you said. Still to confirm - apart from call to finish() while exiting main activity i hope no other cleaning up is needed.

Comment: Please explain what is meant here by handleStuff and handleSomethingElse...exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you do stuff with the data you've received. In your case it data  is the backgroundColor. So you can make a method where you set the background and call it from onActivityResult.

Comment: Oh thanks. But I am setting the background colors in custom adapter code in getView function - so that gets done during onCreate of the gridview class (when setAdapter is called) of whose items backgrounds i m setting. Is this the best way? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't possible for you to create a new method which updates the background color for the items and then invalidates ( so it gets updated)?